# Python3 gtk3 GtkFileChooserDialog does not appear

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I'm trying to make a simple app. Using Glade to make GUI and python3. There is one button, on the headerbar, that opens the file chooser dialogue. When I press it function prints out a message, but the file chooser dialogue does not appear. And no error messages. What am I doing wrong?

Console Output, no additional errors:

```sh
$ python3 example.py

(example.py:50697): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:32:14.333: Content added to the action area of a dialog using header bars

(example.py:50697): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:32:14.333: Content added to the action area of a dialog using header bars
on_open_dialog
```

My python code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyApp:
  def __init__(self):
      self.column_names = False
      self.drop_nan = False
      self.df = None

      self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
      self.builder.add_from_file("example.glade")
      self.builder.connect_signals(self)

      self.window = self.builder.get_object("MainWindow")
      self.window.show_all()


  def on_open_dialog(self, widget):
    dialog = self.builder.get_object("open_file_dialog")
    response = dialog.run
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
      print("ok btn")
      filename = dialog.get_filename()
      self.load_table(filename)
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
      print("cancel btn")
      dialog.close()
    dialog.close()
    print("on_open_dialog")

  def on_close_dialog(self, widget, event):
    print("on_close_dialog")
    return self.builder.get_object("open_file_dialog").hide_on_delete()

  def on_destroy(self, event):
    Gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  MyApp()
  Gtk.main()
```

And my Glade file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="MainWindow">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <object class="GtkHeaderBar">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <property name="show-close-button">True</property>
        <signal name="destroy" handler="on_destroy" swapped="no"/>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">gtk-open</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
            <property name="use-stock">True</property>
            <signal name="pressed" handler="on_open_dialog" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkFileChooserDialog" id="open_file_dialog">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="type-hint">dialog</property>
    <property name="transient-for">MainWindow</property>
    <property name="create-folders">False</property>
    <child internal-child="vbox">
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">2</property>
        <child internal-child="action_area">
          <object class="GtkButtonBox">
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <property name="layout-style">end</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
                <property name="label">gtk-cancel</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can-focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives-default">True</property>
                <property name="use-stock">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
                <property name="label">gtk-ok</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can-focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives-default">True</property>
                <property name="use-stock">True</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
    <action-widgets>
      <action-widget response="-6">button1</action-widget>
      <action-widget response="-5">button2</action-widget>
    </action-widgets>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `dialog.run()`, with `()` at the end. In your code, you have `dialog.run`, without the `()`.

Comment: Yes of course. Thank You! Annoying that it does not show any error about that.

Comment: You're welcome! I suggest you delete your question, since it was caused by a typo. The reason that it doesn't show an error is because sometimes you would _want_ to simply pass the function as an argument instead of calling it. For example, in your UI file, you connect the button's `pressed` signal to `on_open_dialog`. If you were to put that in your code instead, it would look like this: `button.connect("clicked", self.on_open_dialog)`: you're giving the button the function itself, not the result of _calling_ the function. This is a common scenario, especially in event-driven programming.

Comment: But of course, if Python's error messages were better, it would be able to figure out when you needed parentheses, and give you a warning when you didn't use them.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).